# Estimating remainder without modular principles

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the remainder when $5^{125}$ is divided by $124$. Can I calculate this using Euclid's lemma and not using modular principles

Answer (score 1):

$5^3=1+124$

$\implies(5^3)^{41}=(1+124)^{41}$
$=1+\binom{41}1124^1+\binom{41}2124^2\cdots+\binom{41}{40}124^{40}+124^{41}\equiv1\pmod{124}$

$\implies5^{125}=5^2\cdot(5^3)^{41}\equiv25\cdot1\pmod{124}$

Answer (score 0):

No need of rules of modular-arithmetic. You can write $124$ as: $124=5^3-1$

Now you can note that : $$5^{125}-5^{122}$$ is amultiple of $124$.

Indeed $5^{122}(5^3-1)$ is a multiple of $124$.
Therefore $5^{125}$ has the same remainder of $5^{122}$ Therefore you can repeat the procedure for $5^{122}$ and obtain that $5^{122}-5^{119}$ multiple of $124$. Therefore  $5^{122}$ has the same remainder of$5^{119}$.

At the end you obtain that $5^{125}$ has the same remainder of$5^{2}=25$.